# In Python 3 with BeautifulSoup, the print(soup.get_text()) generates an error ('NoneType' object is not callable) in the following code:

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This code generates a NoneType object error.  The "print(soup.get_text())" is indicated as the  problem.  How do I fix this?

```
import urllib
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

base_url = "http://www.galactanet.com/oneoff/theegg_mod.html"

url = (base_url)
content = urllib.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
print(soup.get_text())
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using Python 2, not Python 3. This is evident from you using `urllib.urlopen(url)`, which doesn't work in Python 3.

In addition you have installed BeautifulSoup 3, which is an old version and doesn't work with Python 3.

But, you are reading the documentation for BeautifulSoup 4.

Solution:
Install BeautifulSoup4, and change the import line to

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

And you are good to go.

Comment: Is there an equivalent command to soup.get_text() in BeautifulSoup 3?

Comment: @gokun: Is there a reason you can't use bs4?

Comment: I am using Canopy (Python 2.7) and am not ready to leave its confines.

Comment: @gokun: As I understand it Beautiful Soup isn't a part of canopy, which means you *can* use bs4.

Comment: I'm with Python 2.7 and BeautifulSoup 3, what's the equivalent to get_text()?

Comment: I just crafted a function and posted in an answer. Can be useful if someone is not in the position to upgrade BS or Python

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the line

```
content = urllib.urlopen(url)
```

it should be

```
content = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
```

Here is a example using BeautifulSoup4.

```
import bs4 
import urllib
url = raw_input("Enter url - ")
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)
tags = soup('a')
for tag in tags:
    print tag.get('href',None)
```

Answer (score 0):

For those with Python 2.7 and BeautifulSoup 3 here is a function which goal is to scrape off as many fluff as possible and stick with the textual content:

```
from django.utils.html import escape
from django.utils.text import Truncator

from BeautifulSoup import MinimalSoup, CData, Comment, Declaration, ProcessingInstruction, \
    BeautifulStoneSoup
```

...

```
def get_text(self):
    soup = MinimalSoup(self.htmlxml, convertEntities=BeautifulStoneSoup.ALL_ENTITIES)
    comments = soup.findAll(text=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment))
    [comment.extract() for comment in comments]
    cdatas = soup.findAll(text=lambda text: isinstance(text, CData))
    [cdata.extract() for cdata in cdatas]
    decls = soup.findAll(text=lambda text: isinstance(text, Declaration))
    [decl.extract() for decl in decls]
    pis = soup.findAll(text=lambda text: isinstance(text, ProcessingInstruction))
    [pi.extract() for pi in pis]
    return Truncator(escape(re.sub('\n', '', re.sub('<.*?>', '', soup.renderContents())))).chars(limit)
```